# How to setup alerts for memory usage in Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, memory-management

That, basically. I have a Rails 5 application but really more on a general level Im trying to find a way to get email alerts when my dynos reach certain memory usage threshold. Im using one web and one worker. Cant find anything.

Comment: What dyno type are you running on? Heroku provides threshold alerting on 1X and up...which seems to be what you are asking about

Comment: Im running on 2x, however Heroku only offers alerts for response times and failed requests for what I see. I had to install an add-on called Logentries but this only alerts you when you get an R14 error from what ive seen so far.

Comment: @GaroSan Any resolution on this? I'm also looking for this solution.

Comment: @MAckerman not really, I just had to drop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku has an 'Application metrics' page which can also alert you on some conditions. However there is no option for alerting for memory usage. We have asked Heroku support and this is their answer:

> Yes, unfortunately there's not a built-in way to receive alerts about
>   memory usage. However, you could potentially set up your Papertrail
>   instance to alert you if your app emits an R14 or an R15. Keep in mind
>   that those are cases where it might be too late to take any corrective
>   action on memory as it is already alerting a disruption to the app.
>
> For more granularity, you'll need to enable the log-runtime-metrics
>   lab so that your memory usage is printed to your application logs:
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics.
>
> You can also use a log drain to parse, chart, and setup alerts for
>   those errors. Librato is the most common tool I see customers using
>   for that kind of workflow: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/librato.

Relying on Papertrail is good enough for us for now, but we are still exploring other options. One option is to simply use the Rails app to report its own memory usage, for example through a system call like this `pmap #{Process.pid} | tail -1`. Another option is to use Monit (https://mmonit.com/) but it's not very easy to set it up and configure. (You will need a custom build pack to run this on Heroku.) Also Heroku supports some 3rd party addons for monitoring which can send alerts, like New Relic.

Answer (score 1):

You can't in Heroku, but the best solution I've found so far is to use [App Signal](https://appsignal.com)

They allow you to set up custom alerts for any metric they track, including host memory usage.

App Signal is a pretty solid APM in general too, so you can ditch New Relic, Scout, or whatever other tool you might be using as well.